# How can I custom url to access_denied from SpringSocial Facebook?

Tags: spring-security, spring-social-facebook

In [ProviderSignInController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/master/spring-social-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ProviderSignInController.java) we have a method oauth2ErrorCallback.
When the user cancel authorization in facebook this method redirect to:

```
/signin?error=access_denied&error_description=Permissions+error
```

I need customize this url, how can do it?

I need redirect to my page, customized.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I overrride the ProvidersignInCrontroller, but my feeling say to me that this is not the definitive solution

```
class MyProviderSignInController extends ProviderSignInController {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyProviderSignInController.class);

    private String urlToOauth2ErrorCallback;

    public MyProviderSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, SignInAdapter signInAdapter) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, signInAdapter);
    }

    public void defineUrlToOauth2ErrorCallback(String urlToOauth2ErrorCallback) {
        this.urlToOauth2ErrorCallback = urlToOauth2ErrorCallback;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{providerId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "error")
    public RedirectView oauth2ErrorCallback(@PathVariable String providerId, @RequestParam("error") String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "error_description", required = false) String errorDescription,
            @RequestParam(value = "error_uri", required = false) String errorUri, NativeWebRequest request) {
        log.warn("Error during authorization: " + error);

        if (urlToOauth2ErrorCallback != null) {
            return new RedirectView(urlToOauth2ErrorCallback, false);
        }

        return super.oauth2ErrorCallback(providerId, error, errorDescription, errorUri, request);
    }

}
```